# Rails - sort by parents attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following 2 tables

Table "public.friendships"

```
   Column   |            Type             |
------------+-----------------------------+
 id         | integer                     |
 user_id    | integer                     |
 friend_id  | integer                     |
 created_at | timestamp without time zone |
 updated_at | timestamp without time zone |
```

Table "public.users"

```
         Column         |            Type             |
------------------------+-----------------------------+
 id                     | integer                     |
 encrypted_password     | character varying(128)      |
 password_salt          | character varying(128)      |
 email                  | character varying(255)      |
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

associations between these tables are as follows

```
#user.rb
has_many :friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', :foreign_key => 'user_id', :dependent => :destroy

#friendship.rb
belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User'
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
```

I am trying to find all friendships of a user

```
@user = current_user
@friendships = @user.friendships
```

Everything works great. But I want to list all friends of the current user, sorted in alphabetical order of their `first_name`. I tried

```
 @friendships = @user.friendships.order(:first_name)
```

of course it doesn't work. What is the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put an order clause on the [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

```
has_many :friendships, -> { joins(:user).order('users.first_name') }, foreign_key: 'user_id', dependent: :destroy
```

Then this will work automatically

```
@friendships = @user.friendships
```

Comment: When I use this I am getting `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column friendships.first_name does not exist
LINE 1: ...ERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "friendships...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "friendships".* FROM "friendships"  WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "friendships"."first_name" ASC`  error when I try to do `<% @friendships.each do |friendship| %>` in my view

Comment: @TonyVincent Ok, I misread your question, have a go at the edit. If that doesn't work I'm off to the coffee machine (even though I don't drink coffee)